# react-native-maps iOS error

Tags: react-native

Trying to add airbnb/react-native-maps to my react native project and follow the guide at https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md. Option 1,

Option 1: Cocoapods - Same as the included AirMapsExplorer example

```
Setup your Podfile like the included example/ios/Podfile then run pod install. (If you do not need GoogleMaps support for iOS, then you can probably completely skip this step.)
Open your project in xCode workspace
Drag the following folder into your project:
node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirMaps/
If you need GoogleMaps support also drag this folder into your project:
node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirGoogleMaps/
```

After done, I cannot run the project in Xcode, it gives the error, `'RCTImageLoader.h' file not found`.

I hv tried run `rnpm link` and it cannot go through,

```
rnpm-link info Android module react-native-maps is already linked
rnpm-link info Linking react-native-maps ios dependency
rnpm-link ERR! It seems something went wrong while linking. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/nedved/Desktop/NativeCreditcard_office/node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirGoogleMaps.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm/issues
```

I can find the file `/Users/XXXX/node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirGoogleMaps.xcodeproj`  locally, but when clicking, "Project /Users/XXXX/node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirGoogleMaps.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file."

Any idea?